# Why has an answer that appears to be plagiarised been allowed to stand?

Tags: discussion, moderation

An answer to [this question](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/23937/how-was-jupiter-formed) appears to be an unattributed copy of a space.com article.

I flagged this, but my flag has been rejected by a moderator.

My (perhaps limited) understanding is that whilst wholesale, *attributed* cut-and-pasting seems to be tolerated (though my personal view is that this is very poor and damages the reputation of Astronomy SE), *unattributed* plagiarism is outlawed and a potential copyright infringement.

Is there an explanation for why this post has not been removed? Unless the contributor owns the intellectual copyright to the original space.com article, then shouldn't it be replaced with a comment that provides a link to the material that appears to have been stolen?

See also [Attribution of sources used in questions and answers](https://astronomy.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/57/attribution-of-sources-used-in-questions-and-answers) and [Is it ever acceptable for answers to cut and paste answers from other sites?](https://astronomy.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/286/is-it-ever-acceptable-for-answers-to-cut-and-paste-answers-from-other-sites)

Comment: Please use flags for this purpose. Meta is ok, but flags should be your first line of defense. The post has been deleted.

Comment: @called2voyage "I flagged this, but my flag has been rejected by a moderator." It was deleted 2 days after this post and 3 days after I flagged it. Maybe I don't understand what rejection of a flag by a moderator means?

Comment: Strange, the flag doesn't show up in the moderator action history, but it does show up in your flag history, and it doesn't show as rejected. It says it was marked as helpful. You might have stumbled across a bug.